# Arrange videos by date although some aren't in folders?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-management

I have some videos in folders and some aren't in folders so when I want to arrange by "date modified" the ones without folders stay in a bunch at the top in order and the ones in folders stay together.  I want to arrange ALL the folders by "date modified" without them splitting by "Type".

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Search result in this case.  At the root (start) of your video folder, type in `kind:videos` into Search (top right). By default, it will search recursively.

Then change the Search Result to details view.  Then you can sort by Date modified.

Edit:

You can also tack on to the Search command `modified:today` or whatever time span.